# No further automation after photo upload with selenium autoit

Tags: selenium, autoit

Photo uploaded successfully using below code. but no further automation is able to do like save.

Some selenium unsupport error im getting :

```
/public void click6(String ObjectName, ChromeDriver driver2) throws IOException   
driver2.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty(ObjectName))).click();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Tester\\Documents\\nall\\SchoolERP test\\FileUpload.exe");
driver2.findElement(By.id("input_6")).sendKeys("AutoIT in Selenium");                   
driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='schoollogo']")).click();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and "[Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest?noredirect=1&lq=1)"

Comment: At least show us the exact error you get and on what line of code? Also add the relevant HTML.